# How to set width of toast in Android?

Tags: android, toast

Is there any easy way to `set width` of the `Toast` without customizing it?

Thanks,
Nital

**Update:**

there is no such method...
i finally customized it in this way...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: I thing Toast is a default property of the android.

Comment: you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Comment: @Rishabh "i already knw that :) but your answer dint work out..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the following way to set width and height of toast.

### How to set width and height to toast

### CancelProgressDialog.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CancelProgressDialog extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);

        /* Create a very simple button */

        Button b = new Button(this);

        this.setContentView(b);

        b.setText("Show ProgressBar...");

//      b.setOnClickListener(myProgressBarShower);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View toastRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) toastRoot.findViewById(R.id.toasttext);
        tv.setWidth(200);
        tv.setHeight(100);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);

        toast.setView(toastRoot);
        toast.show();
//      toast.setText("I am toast");
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


    }
}
```

### customtoast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I am toast"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/toasttext"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks deepak, i have already done it using [customize_toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)..  just see my Update

Comment: I'm stuck w/ the same problem but I have a picture and a textview, so just setting the dimensions of the TextView doesn't work.

Answer (score 16):

Use

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
```

Comment: pls show me this methods here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html ... i have to be blind

Comment: how we can change toast's width to given one with this? ... this option makes  only Toast to fill parent

Comment: This makes the toast fill the whole width, how can I give margin to this so it doesn't touch the sides?

Comment: Create a custom layout with below hierarchy linear layout-> linear layout -> textview and set margin at 2nd level linear layout with toast msg background.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it with another layer of layout and it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <!-- customize your width and height here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_check_box"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/message"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```